# Charles does not see device connection attempt (Cannot get "Connection from X" message)

Tags: android, proxy, charles-proxy

I'm using multiple Android devices, and I know I'm supposed to get the following message once I setup the proxy on my phone to use Charles.

[image]

I can use Charles without any problem for Nougat devices (tried both the AVD and a physical device), but then I try on other devices that use Marshmallow and below (Again, both the AVD and a physical device), I do not receive this message, hence, I cannot continue my work. If I try to search the 'getssl' page on google, I'll get the 'err_cert_authority_invalid' error.

Also, what happens if I accidentally Deny? How can I fix this?

Comment: At least for v4.2.5 it was enough to Restart Charles. Then the message came again.

Comment: Still enough in v4.2.7